# What's the best management distro for xCat?

Tags: linux, cluster

I want to deploy a **iDataPlex** cluster but using only free software with **xCat**. The **xCat** start guide uses **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5** in the management node.

What's the best free distro to install instead of **RHEL** in the management node?

I looking for the most compatible distro with **RHEL**. Maybe the best options should be **Fedora**[1] or **Centos**[2].

- [1] **Fedora** is the upstream of **RHEL**
- [2] **Centos** is a community distro using **RHEL** sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS. It is meant to be a completely compatible replacement for RHEL, including binary compability.

Comment: And did you recomend me the lattest stable 6.2, or 5.8?

Comment: If the app in question allows it, v6.2, since this is maintained for three years longer than v5. I don't know the product you are talking about though, so it might be it requires v5.